# Factory tries to create two objects with same properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs, faker

I'm writing tests for an express app that implements a user CRUD. Before writing integration tests, I made a factory that would create users for the tests:

`factories.js`

```
import faker from 'faker';
import { factory } from 'factory-girl';

import User from '../../src/app/models/User';

factory.define('User', User, {
  name: faker.name.firstName(),
  email: faker.internet.email(),
  password: faker.internet.password(),
  admin: false,
});

export default factory;
```

Nice. Now whenever I needed to create a user for tests, I would just have to use `factory.create()`, right? Wrong. In one of the test suites I need two users, one that is admin and other that isn't. So I wrote this setup/teardown:

```
let user, admin; 

const createUsers = async () => {
  // Runs ok 
  user = await factory.create('User');

  // Error
  admin = await factory.create('User', { admin: true });
};

const removeUsers = async () => {
  await user.remove();
  await admin.remove();
};

beforeAll(async () => {
  await createUsers();
});

afterAll(async () => {
    await removeUsers();
    mongoose.connection.close();
});
```

`user = await factory.create(...)` runs fine, but `admin = await factory.create(...)` raises a `MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection`.

This is because the factory tries to create a user with an email that is already in use (email is unique for the model User). I could ensure that wouldn't happen by passing a specific email to the create method in the same way I passed `admin: true`, but that wouldn't make much sense since I created the factory to avoid this kind of trouble.

Can you guys point out what am I doing wrong here? I guess it has something to do with the way I defined my factory. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: As suggested, I fixed it by using `factory.sequence`.

```
factory.define('User', User, {
  name: factory.sequence('User.name', () => faker.name.firstName()),
  lastName: factory.sequence('User.lastName', () => faker.name.lastName()),
  email: factory.sequence('User.email', () => faker.internet.email()),
  password: factory.sequence('User.password', () => faker.internet.password()),
  redefinePassword: false,
  admin: false,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While faker.internet.email() will create a new fake email every time it is called, you only call it once when defining your template object for the factory. Look into the factory.sequence API for a way to make the factory run some code for each object being created https://www.npmjs.com/package/factory-girl#defining-factories

Or simply pass the function faker.internet.email, without the () and I think factory-girl will call that function each time as well, you can also make your define call take a function that returns this object (after calling faker.internet.email()), so many options!

Comment: It works just fine now. Going to edit it with the working factory, thanks!